# When case in sql does not support in cassandra cql

Tags: mysql, cassandra

I was using `mysql` earlier. Now for specific reason had to move to `cassandra`. Now I am facing some incompatibility issue with my `mysql queries` in `cassandra cql` . For example `when case` in `mysql` it seems does not support in `cql` . How to make this `sql` work in `cassandra`

```
SELECT age, sum(case when age>0 and age<=10 then 1 else 0 end)   as x0, 
sum(case when age>10 and age<=20 then 1 else 0 end) as x1
FROM user_table where location_id=24
```

I am getting the following error:

```
SyntaxException: line 1:32 no viable alternative at input 'when' (... age, sum([case] when...)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you mind to remove the hotizontal scrollbars? These decreases the readability.

Comment: @AshrafulIslam you have mentioned `you can just convert mysql query to cql` . How can I convert above `mysql query` to `cql`

Comment: Cassandra have huge restriction on select query, Ex. you can only use where clause on primary key fields only, cassandra select node where to store data based on partition key only etc. So you have to make table table schema in such a way that you can query and retrieve data efficiently.

Comment: there is huge difference between sql and cql. you can't just convert mysql query to cql. In mysql you used normalization, but in cassandra you have use de-normalization etc

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible at all to map this query to cql. Things are different with cassandra.

When designing your system you should have in mind, what queries you have to run and design it accordingly. This is given by the fact that you can only access the data in a way like it was written.

Last but not least the part where you are creating sums, is probably something which you would like to do on the client side.

Best